# Open .eml file in compose mode in any client

Tags: email, outlook, thunderbird, eml

I have composed a mail and stored as .eml file. I need to open this .eml file in compose mode with default email client application configured in the system.

Its getting opened in read mode. I went through all threads in stackoverflow. Everyone's solution is adding header X-Unsent: 1. Though I add this header in .eml file, It is getting opened in read mode. Am I missing anything here?

```
X-Unsent: 1
To: "Manikandan TK" <manirulz88@gmail.com>
Subject: Test
Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 08:56:52 +0000
Message-Id: <em206d8b63-c287-48b1-93ae-b9ac686e1bc7@jamshedpur>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="------=_MB56B3DE95-5830-47CE-BE69-82C5C00F1F9A"
```

Comment: Did you try to save an email in the .eml format and then re-open it manually? Do you get the same results?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't get any email client to open a .eml file in compose mode just by changing the headers of the message. In fact, I'm almost 100% certain that won't work ever.

The best you can hope for is some command-line or way of scripting each individual email client to open the message in compose mode by some other means.

For that, you'll need to read the documentation for each email client you hope to support and/or read thru it's source code if it is open source. You might also have some luck emailing the developers of said client and asking them how to do it (if it's even possible).

I suspect, however, that the answer you'll get back is "not possible".

That said, many mail clients *do* support open of "mailto" urls which might be the best you can expect to be able to do.